# ASp.MVC HTTP Post not redirecting to action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-post, http-get, redirecttoaction

I have 2 index methods in my controller, one of them is a GET and the other is a POST which is used on a form on the page.

When I submit my form, when the page refreshes, it shows a blank page instead of running through my GET index method and ideally reload that page.

**POST METHOD**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Index(ProductViewModel product)
    {
        try
        {
            var productContract = Mapper.Map<ProductViewModel, ProductContract>(product);
            _productService.CreateProduct(productContract);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
        RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

**GET METHOD**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        _productService = new ProductServiceClient();
        var brandSerice = new ProductBrandServiceClient();
        var categoryService = new ProductCategoryServiceClient();

        var productPageViewModel = new ProductPageViewModel();
        var productViewModelList = new List<ProductViewModel>();
        var productBrandsViewModelList = new List<ProductBrandViewModel>();
        var productCategoriesViewModelList = new List<ProductCategoryViewModel>();

        try
        {
            productViewModelList.AddRange(_productService.GetProducts().Select(Mapper.Map<ProductContract, ProductViewModel>));
            productBrandsViewModelList.AddRange(brandSerice.GetProductBrands().Select(Mapper.Map<ProductBrandContract, ProductBrandViewModel>));
            productCategoriesViewModelList.AddRange(categoryService.GetProductCategories().Select(Mapper.Map<ProductCategoryContract, ProductCategoryViewModel>));

            productPageViewModel.ProductList = productViewModelList;

            productPageViewModel.ProductBrands = new SelectList(productBrandsViewModelList, "Id", "Description");
            productPageViewModel.ProductCategories = new SelectList(productCategoriesViewModelList, "Id", "Description");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return View(productPageViewModel);
    }
```

Comment: Note:  Your `catch` blocks are not only superfluous, they're detrimental.  They should just be removed entirely.

Comment: You have made a statement and not really explained why, What will be the reason @David

Comment: They're superfluous because they don't actually do anything.  They're detrimental because they throw away stack trace information and replace it with a new stack trace, effectively hiding where the actual exception originated.

Comment: I added this because i am making a call to the to my wcf service, shouldnt there be a catch for if there is a problem in the service call ? or should ths try catch only be in the service layer ?. @David

Comment: You should catch exceptions where you can actually *handle* them in some way.  Which you're not doing.  And you shouldn't *delete* important information about the exception, which you are doing.  This has nothing to do with WCF or any service layer.  These catch blocks don't *do* anything to stop the exception, all they do is break it before allowing it to continue up the stack.  Since you're allowing the exception to continue anyway, just let the *original* exception go straight through the method without modifying it.

Comment: @David that's a better explanation, thank you. Will remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a result:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ProductViewModel product)
{
    // ...

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```